# Trigger in Mysql Server 4.0 not function if

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

When I try to execute this trigger I get the following error in mysql server 5.0.

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventario
BEFORE INSERT ON inventario.det_retencion_cv
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if NEW.ivafuente = 'fuente' THEN
        SET NEW.ivafuente = 'renta';
    END if;
END
```

the error

```
Executing Query. Wait ...
MySQL ERROR:

Trigger in wrong schema
QUERY:

CREATE TRIGGER inventario
BEFORE INSERT ON inventario.det_retencion_cv
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if NEW.ivafuente = 'fuente' THEN
        SET NEW.ivafuente = 'renta';
    END if;
END
```

Help me

Comment: In which database/schema is the `det_retencion_cv` table?  Note that you are also naming your trigger after a possible database name, which might not be what you intend to do.

Comment: Everything is fine in the database schema but when I want to use the conditional (if statements) there eme generates the error. I'm working with Mysql Server and DBManager as a manager